# Angular 8 - Get config parameters from 'ng serve..' (Ej. --configuration)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get the value from the configuration param when I run Angular Ej. =>

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng s -c custom-value
```

I need to get these 'custom-value' from the command and use it before the App is launched (probably in the *main.ts* file)

```js
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
if (configValue === 'custom-value') {
  /** Do something special*/
}
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a configuration parameter taken in, this should be part of the `environment.ts`-file.

Create a custom environment-file, and link that a new "configuration" in the `angular.json`-file.

If you've named your configuration as "bob", you can then serve your application (for development purposes as:

`ng serve -c bob`

or build it as:

`ng build -c bob`

But there's no way to feed in "one of" configuration properties, it's the entire `environment.ts`-file you're switching upon.

Granted, since the `environment.ts`-file, you can easily merge TypeScript objects together (have a look at `Object.assign` or the ES2015 spread operator).

For additional documentation related to the `angular.json`-file, please consult the documentation, found here:
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Comment: Hi Anders! I'm actually doing this to load each `environment.ts` file (configurated in the `angular.json` file too) , but I need to pass another filter before doing the `Object.asign` and it's defined by the own value passed in the `ng serve....` command. Do you know if I can check this value from the `main.ts` file??

Comment: Since angular is using Webpack underneath the hood, I don't see what would stop you from using `require` to load the `angular.json`-file (if that's what you're asking). Now... another question is if it's a good idea, which I would determine it not to be.